# Update multidimensional array key value

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, updates

I'm had crated multidimensional array using PHP from Wordpress. Currently I'm adding admin option to Wordpress and created a fews inputs in plugin option page. In each input tag required name and value attribute. How to update the value key from multidimensional array ? I'm having problem update it.

```
$option_settings = (array(
   array('Aries', array(
      array(  'Name'=>'id_name1', 
                      'Work'=> 3, 
                      'Health'=> 4,
                      'Love'=> 5,
                      'Money'=> 6
)))));
add_option('general_settings',$option_settings);
register_setting('general_settings','general_settings');
add_settings_section('main_section','General Settings',array($this,'main_section_cb'), __FILE__); //id, title of section, cb which page ?
add_settings_field('Workload_rate',"Workload rate: ",array($this,'Workload_rate_setting'),__FILE__,'main_section');

public function Workload_rate_setting()
{
echo "<input name='' type='text' value='{$this->options['Workload_rate_setting']}' />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The php function var_dump() will help you see what is in variables.
I suggest you use it on your array after adding settings:

```
var_dump(option_settings);
```